# Simpy Simulation for Job Shop Problem, using parralel ressources

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to programm and simulate a the job shop problem with the simpy modul (https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). At the end I want to optimize the problem with reinforcement learning. However, my problem is when I try to simulate the created sequence (not yet generated by the agent) simpy uses a time for all resources (machines). I had thought about passing the individual operations with a while loop to the timeout event of simpy and then simulate. However, it does not work. Can someone help me? Here is my code so far.

```
15 15
6 94 12 66  4 10  7 53  3 26  2 15 10 65 11 82  8 10 14 27  9 93 13 92  5 96  0 70  1 83 
4 74  5 31  7 88 14 51 13 57  8 78 11  8  9  7  6 91 10 79  0 18  3 51 12 18  1 99  2 33 
1  4  8 82  9 40 12 86  6 50 11 54 13 21  5  6  0 54  2 68  7 82 10 20  4 39  3 35 14 68 
5 73  2 23  9 30  6 30 10 53  0 94 13 58  4 93  7 32 14 91 11 30  8 56 12 27  1 92  3  9 
7 78  8 23  6 21 10 60  4 36  9 29  2 95 14 99 12 79  5 76  1 93 13 42 11 52  0 42  3 96 
5 29  3 61 12 88 13 70 11 16  4 31 14 65  7 83  2 78  1 26 10 50  0 87  9 62  6 14  8 30 
12 18  3 75  7 20  8  4 14 91  6 68  1 19 11 54  4 85  5 73  2 43 10 24  0 37 13 87  9 66 
11 32  5 52  0  9  7 49 12 61 13 35 14 99  1 62  2  6  8 62  4  7  3 80  9  3  6 57 10  7 
10 85 11 30  6 96 14 91  0 13  1 87  2 82  5 83 12 78  4 56  8 85  7  8  9 66 13 88  3 15 
6  5 11 59  9 30  2 60  8 41  0 17 13 66  3 89 10 78  7 88  1 69 12 45 14 82  4  6  5 13 
4 90  7 27 13  1  0  8  5 91 12 80  6 89  8 49 14 32 10 28  3 90  1 93 11  6  9 35  2 73 
2 47 14 43  0 75 12  8  6 51 10  3  7 84  5 34  8 28  9 60 13 69  1 45  3 67 11 58  4 87 
5 65  8 62 10 97  2 20  3 31  6 33  9 33  0 77 13 50  4 80  1 48 11 90 12 75  7 96 14 44 
8 28 14 21  4 51 13 75  5 17  6 89  9 59  1 56 12 63  7 18 11 17 10 30  3 16  2  7  0 35 
10 57  8 16 12 42  6 34  4 37  1 26 13 68 14 73 11  5  0  8  7 12  3 87  2 83  9 20  5 97
```

```
import gym
import simpy
from simpy.events import AnyOf, AllOf, Event
import random
import numpy as np


class JobShop_RL(gym.Env):

   def __init__(self):
       # Reading the Dataset for the JSP
       with open("taillard.txt", "r") as self.data:
           self.read_data = self.data.readline()
           self.line = self.read_data.split()
           # Getting number of Jobs and Machines
           self.jobs = int(self.line[0])
           self.machines = int(self.line[1])
           self.all_jobs = np.zeros((self.jobs, self.machines), dtype=(int, 2))
           # Filling Matrix  with (jobs/number) = (machine/time)
           self.line = self.data.readline()
           job = 0
           self.max_time = 0  # Max time
           self.sum_time = 0  # Sum of the whole time
           self.jobs_duration = np.zeros(self.machines, dtype=int)  # Sum of time for each job

           i = 0
           j = 0

           while job < self.jobs:
               self.line = self.line.split()
               while i <= ((self.jobs + self.machines) - 1):
                   self.all_jobs[job][j] = int(self.line[i]), int(self.line[i + 1])
                   self.jobs_duration[job] += int(self.line[i + 1])
                   self.max_time = max(self.max_time, int(self.line[i + 1]))
                   self.sum_time += int(self.line[i + 1])
                   j += 1
                   i += 2

               self.line = self.data.readline()
               job += 1
               i = 0
               j = 0

       # possible legal actions + the same number for no op for each machine
       # e. g. 15x15 JSSP = 15 legal moves and also 15 no op
       self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(self.machines+self.machines)
       # observation space
       self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box

       # jobs_done = last stage, storing all jobs which are done
       self.jobs_done = []
       # last jobs = represents jobs the last jobs ( = nb of machines) which are done
       #self.last_jobs = np.zeros(self.jobs, dtype=(int, 2))
       # last jobs = represents jobs the last jobs ( = nb of machines) which are done
       self.possible_actions = np.zeros(self.jobs, dtype=(int, 2))
       i = 0
       while i < self.machines:
           self.possible_actions[i] = self.all_jobs[i][0]
           i += 1
       #
       self.counting = np.zeros(self.machines)

       # final order of the job shop problem
       self.final_order = np.zeros_like(self.all_jobs)

       self.simpy_env = simpy.Environment()
       # Store the simpy resources (machines) in the list
       self.machines_sy = []
       i = 0
       while i <= self.machines:
           self.machines_sy.append(simpy.Resource(self.simpy_env, capacity=1))
           i += 1

   def get_operation_index(self, action):
       index_machine = action // self.jobs
       index_operation = action % self.jobs
       #print("INDEX", index_operation, index_machine, self.all_jobs[index_operation][index_machine])
       # Returns the Indizes of the action, [Machine][Operation]
       return index_operation, index_machine

   def get_machine(self, action):
       nb_machine = self.all_jobs[self.get_operation_index(action)]
       return nb_machine[0]

   def machine_process(self, simpy_env, action):
       #Request and timeout the action for each incoming action (if machine is busy its going in the queue)
       machine = self.get_machine(action)
       print("ACTION IN MACHINE PROCESS", action)
       #operation = self.possible_actions[action]
       #operation = self.final_order[machine][int(self.counting[action])]
       #print("OPERATION", operation)

       i = 0
       j = 0

       while i < self.machines:
           while j < self.jobs:
               operation = self.final_order[i][j]
               with self.machines_sy[operation[0]].request() as req:
                   yield req
                   print("Machine ", i, " proceed Operation ", self.final_order[i][j], " at ", simpy_env.now)
                   self.jobs_done.append(self.final_order[machine][int(self.counting[action])])
                   yield simpy_env.timeout(operation[1])  # Operation[1] defines the processing time
                   print("Machine ", i, " released Operation ",
                         self.final_order[i][j], " at ", simpy_env.now)
               j += 1
           if j == 15:
               i += 1
               j = 0


   def is_done(self):
       # Returns True if len(jobs_done) is the same as the sum of operations which need to be done
       # ### Die Anzahl an no ops muss beachtet werden
       if len(self.jobs_done) == self.all_jobs.shape[1]*self.all_jobs.shape[0]:
           return True
       else:
           return False

   def take_action(self, action):
       nb_machine = self.possible_actions[action]
       nb_machine = nb_machine[0]

       self.simpy_env.process(env.machine_process(env.simpy_env, action))
       machine = self.get_machine(action)

       # Filling Final Order
       tmp = np.count_nonzero(self.final_order[nb_machine]) // 2
       self.final_order[nb_machine][tmp] = self.possible_actions[action]

       # Update possible actions
       self.possible_action(action)

   def possible_action(self, action):
       self.counting[action] += 1
       self.possible_actions[action] = self.all_jobs[action][int(self.counting[action])]

   def step(self, action):
       reward = 0
       operation = self.get_operation_index(action)


       if action <= self.machines:
           print("##STEP## NORMALE ACTION", action, self.possible_actions[action])
           self.take_action(action)

           reward = 10
       elif self.machines < action <= self.action_space.n:
           print("NOOP", action)
           reward = -3

       #Check if done
       done = self.is_done()
       #Info is unused
       info = {}

       return reward, done, info

   def reset(self):
       pass

   def render(self, mode='human'):
       pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
   env = JobShop_RL()
   print(env.possible_actions)

   env.step(0)
   print("****## NEXT ##***")
   env.step(1)
   print("****## NEXT ##***")
   env.step(2)
   print("****## NEXT ##***")

   env.simpy_env.run(1000)
```

Comment: do you want the three steps to run at the same time in parallel, or one after another in sequence?

Comment: I notice that: yield simpy_env.timeout(operation[1])  # Operation[1] defines the processing time    operation[1] is zero most of the time